# grails 2.4 jquery path

Tags: jquery, grails, assets, pipeline

I have the following config in BuildConfig file.

```
    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.0"
    compile ':cache:1.1.7'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.7"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"
    runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.3.2'
```

No resources plugin

and application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
//= require bootstrap
```

and application.css

```
*= require main
*= require mobile
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap
```

still, when i load the page i dont see the right path for jquery and hence jquery is not loaded. what am i missing.

when i did a view source this is what i see

```
<script src="/appName/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript" library="jquery"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your settings... are you sure you didn't hardcode the `script` element in your .gsp or placed jquery in `web-app/js/`?

Comment: Thank you. I did forget the tags `<g:javascript library='jquery'/>
    <r:layoutResources/>` in one of the included pages. Now, when I do a view source I dont see the jquery include at all ?

Comment: Because your resources are minimized and bundled together perhaps?

Comment: Here's what I get with the same settings as yours: `<script src="/pdash/assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/pdash/assets/jquery.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>`

Comment: I think you are right.  I see this `<script src="/appName/assets/application-3b1c4b9a4f7a90b4f06ec0921e208cee.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>`  and in application.js I have this `//= require jquery` So, I guess they are bundled. Interesting ! Sorry, I am new to all this.

Comment: unfortunately, i dont have enough credits to upvote you. thanks for your help.

Comment: Almost there:) Upvoted your questions and 2 more points to go!

Comment: You are right, you see the bundled packages, which should include jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to conclude:

- Make sure you do not have any harcoded `<script>` element in your .gsp pointing to jquery.
- If you upgraded from Grails 2.3, make sure you remove all lingering `<g:javascript library='jquery'/>` et `<r:layoutResources/>` statements.
- Make sure you have an `<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>` statement in your layout .gsp
- Make sure you do not have the jquery lib in `web-app/js`

If you do not bundle your resources, you should get the following entries in the HTML source view:

```
<script src="/APPNAME/assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/APPNAME/assets/jquery.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```